# Restclient Set an Array Property

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to create a RestClient at runtime,  One of the properties I want to set seems to be a Bool Array.  `RestClient.RedirectsWithGET` Below is the properties of RedirectWithGET that I want to set but dont understand how.

[image]

I have tried `FRESTClient.RedirectsWithGET := (Post301,Post302,Post303,Put303,Delete303);`
and many other variances. But no luck.  How can I set this at runtime?

Comment: Have you tried using ``[]`` instead of ``()``

Comment: @DelphiCoder yes i have tried that with := []  and RedirectsWithGET[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
RestClient1.RedirectsWithGET := [THTTPRedirectWithGET.Post301,
                                 THTTPRedirectWithGET.Post302,
                                 THTTPRedirectWithGET.Post303,
                                 THTTPRedirectWithGET.Put303,
                                 THTTPRedirectWithGET.Delete303];
```

The reason why you need to prefix each value with `THTTPRedirectWithGET` is because those values are part of `THTTPRedirectWithGET` set. But `RestClient.RedirectsWithGET` expects a set of type `THTTPRedirectsWithGET` which is actually a set of `THTTPRedirectWithGET` set.